# React + jQuery -> Button onClick is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, web

Using ReactJS and jQuery I am adding buttons dynamically to specific div id's in my component like so:

```
$('id_name').html('<button>..text..</button>);
```

However, each of these buttons needs to have onClick functionality, and that is where my problem is.

The code that I need help with is this:

```
export default React.createClass({

        ....

    for(var i = 0; i<this.state.cells.length; i++){
          var id = '#'+this.state.cells[i];
          var mb = $(id).text();
          if(mb.length==0){
            $(id).html("<div id='"+ id +"' class='time-slot'> \
                            <button onClick="+this.buttonActivated()+"> \
                                <span id='message-"+id+"'>Not Assigned</span> \
                            </button> \
                       </div>");
          }
    }

         ....

    buttonActivated: function(){
        console.log("Button Clicked");
    },

         ....

});
```

What is actually happening is that when this page renders the function is run automatically for every button that is rendered, so I am getting 15 console logs saying "Button Clicked", but when I click any of the buttons the function is not triggered.

Comment: write this only `this.buttonActivated` remove `()` it will work :) and dont use jquery, you can easily write these kind of code in react also.

Comment: @MayankShukla I have removed it and now when I click a button i get the following error:

      "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Comment: check the way your HTML is being created, if the syntax is the right one...

Comment: why u r using jquery any specific reason ??

Comment: That's what I've been assigned, unfortunately...

Comment: also it says this:

<button onclick="function" ()="" {="" [native="" code]="" }="">                                          <span id="message-#c1r3">Not Assigned</span>                                        </button>

Answer (score 2):

You should not insert DOM element into another DOM element like this in React. You should render it via JSX and also remove the parentheses from the function.
in your constructor, add :

```
this.buttonActivated = this.buttonActivated.bind(this)
```

in your if statement do:

```
if(mb.length==0){
            $(id).html(<div id={idAsAParam} className="time-slot"> 
                      <button onClick={this.buttonActivated}> 
                           <span id={"message-"+idAsAParam}>Not Assigned</span> 
                      </button>
                </div>);
          }
```

This is only a pseudo suggestion to insert html/element into another DOM object.
I would suggest doing the insertion via a state change within the render function of your component.

This way react will be aware of the click event to listen to.

Comment: When I implement it the way you have described the buttons do not render at all.

Comment: Updated the answer. Also to help you more, you may post more of your code and i can help you further.